# How to download table from Oracle with little server load

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a Oracle server which is very highly loaded. I want to Select big table with several millions rows of data and download the data using SQL Developer. How I can do this with little performance impact of the production database?

Comment: Is your table indexed ? Are you doing a select query with conditions ? Or are you just downloading a full table as it is ?

Comment: More details are needed about the query.  If it's a regular `select * from table;`, then there's no need to worry about its impact.  Are there any joins or parallelism that could potentially eat up CPU and IO, sorts that could use a lot of temporary tablespace, etc.

Answer (score 0):

use oracle's export tool for most efficient dump of data from a table.
example

```
exp user/password tables=mytable query="optional where clause here"
```

Note you have to have oracle client installed to use it.

Comment: But you generally want to avoid the original export utility with 11g.  It may not support some new features, which may cause some problems with the data.